# How to echo(display) my photo in the file path

Tags: php, file-upload

I only know how to store the uploaded files(images), but i dont know how to echo it at the least. Here is my code: and also if you have any idea how to display a specific picture to a specific user, can you give me some codes about it?(pdo if it is possible) and how to connect this to my database so that if the user is logged in, their image uploaded will be displayed on their profile? help please. I can't find a tutorial for this, so if anyone had an idea please help me.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];


    // file properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    //work out the file ext
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
        if($file_error === 0) {
            if($file_size <= 1000000) {

                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'uploadfiles/' . $file_name_new;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                    echo $file_destination;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $file_destination;
```

That just prints the destination path, which does nothing. Use html's `img` tag and provide this path to it.

```
echo "<img src='$file_destination'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you know how to connect to a database:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO mytable (profilepicture) VALUES ($filedestination) WHERE `userid` = '$userid'";
```

this query should put the `$file_destination` in your database. To get this file destionation just use this query:

```
$query2 = "SELECT `profilepicture` FROM mytable WHERE `userid` = '$userid'";
```

after you extracted this query and got the string from your database it is as simple as:

```
echo "<img src=".$profilepic."/>";
```

Comment: i am just making it sure, it only saves the path not the picture/image itself right ?

Comment: No you'll just save your path in the table. The <img> takes that path and will link it to the image in your uploads folder.

Comment: it will only go to the destination but how it will extract the specific picture of the user ?

Comment: you save the picture with query 1 with an user id. this userid is unique to every user. with query 2 you take the picture you assigned to the user. if you want to save more pictures per user then you can make a new table with pictureid, userid and path. this way you only need this query: SELECT `pictureid`, `path` WHERE `userid` = '$userid';

Comment: can I add more ? after i update the photo on the database. I also want to update to new picture and at the same time delete the previous user's photo for lesser space? do you know what I need to do that? thank you so much

Comment: in this case you'll add an update query: `UPDATE `mytable` SET `path`=$newpath WHERE `userid`=$userid ` this will replace the old path with a new one

Comment: i did that, but in my image foler, all of the uploaded image are still there, if necessary i only want the updated photo in there. ?